# getting selected check box value in Mvc asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had displayed check box in a list and i want to access that which check box is selected or not and want to call controller action where i select option from dropdown list

```
<div id="pnlSent" style="display: none">
            <%= Html.DropDownList("select","msgtype") %>
            <% foreach (Usp_GetUserMessagesResult w in (List<Usp_GetUserMessagesResult>)ViewData["UListM"])
               { %>
                <li>
            <div class="question-info">

                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" onclick="function() { alert("df") ; } "  />

                <div class="views count"><span></span></div>
                <div class="question">
                    <div class="meta">Subject:  <%= w.Subject %></div>
                    <div class="meta">To: <%= w.Username  %></div>
                    <h3 class="title"><%= Html.Encode(w.Mesg)%></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <% } %>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net-MVC you should ahve the info that you want to be able to access on the controller side in a form as so, I noticed you did not add an ID to your checkbox, mine is dynamically binded and I am using the HTML helper that comes with asp.net-mvc:

```
   <% using(Html.BeginForm("Retrieve", "Home")) %>//Retrieve is the name of the action while Home is the name of the controller
   <% { %>
        <%foreach (var app in newApps)              { %>  
      <tr> 
           <td><%=Html.CheckBox(""+app.ApplicationId )%></td>      

       </tr>  
    <%} %>
   <input type"submit"/>
 <% } %>
```

then on the controller you could access the information like this:

```
   public ActionResult Retrieve()
   {
    //since all variables are dynamically bound you must load your DB into strings in a for loop as so:
  List<app>=newApps;
  for(int i=0; i<app.Count;i++)
  {


    var checkbox=Request.Form[""+app[i].ApplicationId];
    // the reason you check for false because the Html checkbox helper does some kind of freaky thing for value true: it makes the string read "true, false"
      if(checkbox!="false")
      {
      //etc...almost same for other parameters you want that are in thr form
      }

   }
//of course return your view
return View("Index");//this vaires by the name of your view ex: if Index.aspx
  }
```

This site gives more details on how to check information on the controller as controls are handled in the view: 
http://quickstarts.asp.net/previews/mvc/mvc_HowToRenderFormUsingHtmlHelpers.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to submit this form, and do anything with the checkbox values on the server side, you'll want to give them **name** and **value** attributes (and the name should be the same for each checkbox in the group). The checkbox helper that TStamper mentioned takes care of that for you.

If you just want a client action to happen when the checkbox is ticked or unticked, you can do something like this (I'm assuming that these objects have some kind of key field; I'm calling it **MessageID**):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function handleCheckbox( theBox ) {
  if( theBox.checked) {
    // do checked stuff
  }
  else {
    // do un-checked stuff
  }
}
</script>

...

<input type="checkbox" value="<%= w.MessageID %>" onclick="handleCheckbox(this)"  />
```

Please note that **id** values are required to be unique within an HTML document. So creating lots of checkboxes with the ID "Checkbox1" is not a good idea. (If that input element were runat="server", then .NET would generate a unique HTML **id** from the WebForms **ID**.

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through all of the controls on the div pnlsent and if the control type is a checkbox you can then determine if the checkbox is checked.

Example of looping through controls in VB....

```
 For Each ctrl As Control In Page.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            CType(ctrl, TextBox).BackColor = clr
        Else
            If ctrl.Controls.Count > 0 Then
                SetTextBoxBackColor(ctrl, clr)
            End If
        End If
    Next
```